# Entity framework 4 blog or information page

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to find proper place where can i get all updates regarding EF 4 as we are going to use it for our new project.

Is there any team blog for EF4 from microsoft?
Any other online source?

I am trying to get upto speed with EF 4 but just googling everywhere there seems to be old information and confusion me a lot.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for...
http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/ Enjoy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/efdesign/)  Entity Framework Design

[http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/default.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20100209012807/http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/default.aspx) ADO.Net Team blog

[http://misfitgeek.com/blog/resources-for-learning-the-ado-net-entity-framework/](https://www.ortelcom.com/)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/)

[Entity Framework 4.0 Resources – documentation links, best blog posts and more](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123025820/http://geekswithblogs.net/iupdateable/archive/2009/09/23/entity-framework-4.0-resources-ndash-documentation-links-best-blog-posts.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Julia Lerman (author of "Programming Entity Framework") also has a lot of informationn on her blog [Don't Be Iffy](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/) and on her book web site, [Learn Entity Framework](http://www.learnentityframework.com/). She's currently updating her book content to reflect EF4.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Danny Simmons is the EF dev manager for Microsoft, his blog is: [system.data.objects dev guy](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsimmons/)